# Appointment date

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

Anybody tell me when uk embassy give interview date after online payment does it give days or months because in shenen visa we xcal select date but for uk there is no online reservation by the applicant himself thats y tell me how much time is there between payment and interview thank.you

Comment: Why is this tagged "schengen" if you're asking about an (unspecified) UK embassy? The UK is not, and has never been, in the Schengen area.

Answer (score 1):

After you submit the online application via gov.uk you can access a calendar to book your appointment. Typically the date range is up to 21 days from the date of application, but I imagine appointment availability may depend on the location where you are applying.